# How to implement this design in ADS(Advanced Design System)?

Tags: microwave, microstrip, ads

I was trying to implement this design in ADS. I have used coupled lines with all the dimensions but didn't get the expected result. Can anyone instruct any better way.

[image: design to implement]

[image: expected result]
[image: my_design]
[image: simulated output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what results you expected and what results you got.

Comment: Added the schematic, simulated result, expected result of the design.

Comment: I don't know about ADS but I think you need to add captions to each of those diagrams and charts and explain which is expected and which is actual and why you think you have a problem.

Comment: I'm no expert either but you input and output ports don't appear to be similar.

Comment: What is the x-axis in your expected results plot? Your expected results shows a response as a function of some unknown variable, for a few discrete values of frequency. Your actual results shows the response as a function of frequency, for an unknown value of the unknown frequency. How are we supposed to compare these two plots?

Comment: In both plots X axis represents frequency(GHz) and Y axis represent S21(dB).